# Problem Running Jar File On openSuse: java.io.FileNotFoundException (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, linux, executable-jar, opensuse

I'm trying to run an executable jar file in openSuse by opening the app with double click. When I do so, the app does not start and the terminal opens for a second, displaying the error `java.io.FileNotFoundException (No such file or directory)`, then closes. Running the jar file from command line with root privileges works just fine and opens the app, but I want to open the app by double clicking. This is the code that generates the exception:

```
    File f = new File("configs/configs.json");
    FileReader file = new FileReader(f);
```

Comment: That's got a built in weakness: the path is a relative one, so will fail if run incorrectly. That's before issues of file permissions are considered. What does `ls -l configs/configs.json` print when run from the directory containing directory `configs`?

Comment: The output is:
`-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser users 177 Sep 26 15:25 configs/configs.json`

Comment: OK so readability is not a problem. It's readable by all. That means you're likely assuming wrongly the [current directory](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/91-find-the-current-directory-in-java)

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not the case. The app runs normally when run from the terminal with the `java -jar myApp.jar` command and I also tried building the path using `System.getProperty("user.dir")` and `File.separator` and still didn't work

Comment: Your shortcut is called what? And where is it – on the desktop?

Comment: The app called myApp.jar is placed inside a folder in Home/Documents called MyApp. This is where the other files are as well (i.e. the configs folder with the configs.json file), inside the MyApp folder

Comment: If you want to start it via double click, I would make a launcher using the desktop manager you have. The Exec line should be something like *Exec=java -jar ~/Documents/MyApp/myApp.jar*. Note that the current directory problem should be removed in your code by using an absolute path